# Sqoop oracle connection issue

Tags: oracle, cloudera, hortonworks-data-platform, sqoop

I'm trying to connect to oracle database to check the number of records.

```
Scenario-1:
    [user@hostname ingestion]$ sqoop eval --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname_1:PORT_1/Service_1 --username USER --password PASSWORD --query 'select count(*) from SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1'
        class path is /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar:
        Warning: /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
        Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
        17/05/19 14:50:23 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.5.3.0-37
        17/05/19 14:50:25 INFO hdfs.PeerCache: SocketCache disabled.
        17/05/19 14:50:26 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
        17/05/19 14:50:26 WARN tool.EvalSqlTool: SQL exception executing statement: java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:255)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:387)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:441)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:165)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:35)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:801)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
            at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
            at org.apache.sqoop.manager.OracleManager.makeConnection(OracleManager.java:327)
            at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
            at org.apache.sqoop.tool.EvalSqlTool.run(EvalSqlTool.java:64)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
            at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:76)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:225)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
            at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:243)

Scenario-2:
[user@hostname ingestion]$ sqoop eval --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@//hostname_2:PORT_2/Service_2 --username USER --password PASSWORD --query 'select count(*) from SCHEMA_2.TABLE_2'
        class path is /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/libthrift-0.9.3.jar:
        Warning: /usr/hdp/2.5.3.0-37/accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
        Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
        17/05/19 15:02:21 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.6.2.5.3.0-37
        17/05/19 15:02:23 INFO hdfs.PeerCache: SocketCache disabled.
        17/05/19 15:02:23 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
        17/05/19 15:02:24 INFO manager.OracleManager: Time zone has been set to GMT
        ------------------------
        | COUNT(*)             | 
        ------------------------
        | 43                   | 
        ------------------------
```

The first one is giving me error whereas the second one is giving me the expected result.

Can anyone help?
jar used ojdbc14-10.2.0.4.0.jar

Comment: Try updating from ojdbc14-10.x.x.x.x to ojdbc14-11.x.x.x.x

Answer (score 0):

After spending quite some time found the issue. The edge node where Sqoop is running cannot telnet because of the closed ports(OS Patching was done before week and the linux admins closed the ports and did not open them). 
Once the ports are open in the edge node where sqoop runs I was able to execute the sqoop eval